# Is there a way to combine settings (Mobile/GPS/Bluetooth/etc) into profiles?

Tags: settings, customization

I'd like to setup some combination of On/Off settings and create profiles.  For example, when at home, I'd like Bluetooth/Wifi On, but Mobile Off.  When going to work, I want Mobile On and everything else off.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Locale](http://www.twofortyfouram.com/product.html). It's not the cheapest app, but it is very well made and will allow you to do this. It switches to profiles automatically based on certain conditions too.

For example, when it detects that you are at home it can automatically switch to your Bluetooth/Wi-fi profile and turn off the mobile network.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama). It's similar to Tasker and Locale, but free. I don't know what other differences there are as Llama is the only one I've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Settings Profile - http://www.probeez.com/. I bought both and I prefer Settings Profile (it's also cheaper @ $3.95). There is also a free version that only allows one active rule at a time.

Setting up the profiles in SP is more intuitive (to me). The notification bar displays the active profile(s) and that interface allows you to easily change to a new profile. SP contains a few settings for free that Locale doesn't (i.e. Airplane mode, Dock mode). There are plugins for Locale ($1.99) that can handle this - not sure if there are any free plugins.

I'd recommend trying out the free version to see how setting up profiles work, in general.

Comment: I've used this on my old HTC Eris and my (now) Droid X and it rocks.

Answer (score 1):

http://tasker.dinglisch.net/

Tasker is a bit complicated BUT it is insanely powerful. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

Cyanogenmod 9 can do this. I think CM 7 also had this feature.

Unlike the other solutions, you'd have to switch the profiles manually. The upside is that it integrates into the OS more nicely.

Comment: Where? I could not find it in CM7 or CM7.2. True, CM offers *profiles* -- but not in the sense of this question (automatical location based switching).

Comment: CM doesn't offer automatic switching but the OP didn't actually specify that.

Comment: Hm, reading it again it seems you could be right. But as Wil explicitly bound his settings to *locations*, it seemed the logical conclusion. OK, let's leave it to Wil to decide :)

Comment: The question is two years old so I was mostly answering to the world at large :)

Comment: Ah, OK -- so never mind xD